# html5 video jumps to end for long videos after playback starts

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, jetty

I am still trying to get this html 5 playback of video & audio with jetty to work error free. For large videos I notice the video plays up to 75% (just an estimate) then jumps to the end.This never happens with shorter videos but consistently happens on videos more than 10 minutes or so. I don't see any errors in the logs or browser debugger window. Here are the range requests and also the couple errors that do get logged but I don't think are related.

Video

```
Status Code:206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:16001618
Content-Range:bytes 0-16001617/16001618
Content-Type:video/webm
Server:Jetty(9.3.z-SNAPSHOT)

REQUEST
Connection:keep-alive
Range:bytes=0-
```

Audio

```
Status Code:206 Partial Content

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:9044858
Content-Range:bytes 0-9044857/9044858
Content-Type:audio/wav

REQUEST
Range:bytes=0-
```

Video

```
Status Code:206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:10834
Content-Range:bytes 15990784-16001617/16001618
Content-Type:video/webm

REQUEST
Connection:keep-alive
Range:bytes=15990784-
```

Video

```
Status Code:206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:12069458
Content-Range:bytes 3932160-16001617/16001618
Content-Type:video/webm

REQUEST
Connection:keep-alive
Range:bytes=3932160-
```

Like I said this happens consistently for larger videos so I don't think the videos are corrupted. But no errors are returned except the following which does not stop video playing anyway based on the time this error occurs:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 0-11229438/11229439
Content-Length: 11229439
Content-Type: video/webm
, Content-Length=11229439, ScreenID=117435}: {1}, 
   com.service.,java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
   at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.close(IteratingCallback.java:427)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onClose(HttpConnection.java:489)
```

Code that handles the requests:

```
        if(parameters.containsKey(Constants.PARAM_CONTENT_LENGTH)) {
            totalLength =  java.lang.Math.toIntExact((long)  
                parameters.get(Constants.PARAM_CONTENT_LENGTH));    
         } else {
            String range = 
                 parameters.get(Constants.PARAM_RANGE_REQUEST).toString(); 
            String[] ranges = range.split("=")[1].split("-");
             from = Integer.parseInt(ranges[0]);
             if(from >= 0 && from < totalLength) {
                 to = (totalLength - 1); 
                 if (ranges.length == 2) {
                    to = Integer.parseInt(ranges[1]);
                    if (to >= totalLength) {
                        to = (int) (totalLength - 1);
                    }
                 }
             } else {
                to = -1;
             }
        }
    }

    return new ContentRange(from, to, totalLength);
```

Code that writes to the stream:

```
    BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream (outputStream);
    Buffer b = new Buffer();
    long skipped =0;
    int byteLength = 0;

    do {
        inputStream.read(b);

        int len    = b.getLength();
        byte[] data   = (byte[]) b.getData();
        int  offset = b.getOffset();
        if (len > 0) {
            if(skipped < from) {             
              if(skipped + len <= from) {     
                  skipped += len;
              } else {                       
                  offset += (from - skipped);
                  len -= (from - skipped);
                  skipped = from;
              }
            } 
            if(to >= 0) {
                if(from + byteLength + len <= to) {
                } else {
                    len = (to + 1) - (from + byteLength);
                }
            } 

            byteLength+= len;
            bytesWrittenObj.bytesWritten = byteLength;

            bout.write(data, offset, len);
        } 
    } while (!b.isEOM());

    bout.flush();
```

Comment: `Connection:keep-alive` means you are using HTTP/1.0 with HTML5 video? Why not use HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 instead?

Comment: You will need to show your code that is serving the video/audio streams (why they are separate I still don't understand).

Comment: The decision not to combine the audio and video is not from me. I have to go with the requirements. I narrowed down symptoms in that this does not occur when letting the video play without attempting to seek at any point. Added a portion of code but  I unfortunately cannot share the full code as there are too many components to create a working demo as per our last conversation. Thanks much.

Comment: Had to handle the partial range returns myself & not jetty as the video file was not static and dynamically generated.

Comment: I think this has to do with how chrome handles the larger videos. It seems that if you allow chrome to download the full video first, then you can seek with no issues.

Comment: This technique is flawed.  You are writing (using old school blocking techniques) the entire range.   No wonder you get idle timeouts.   This either needs to use Async I/O to benefit from backpressure the client is giving you, or rip all of this out and let Jetty handle the serving of the static content itself (which is done with a backpressure  aware technique too)

Comment: Thanks again @Joakim; I will go back to letting Jetty handle this . Hopefully the PM agrees. Appreciate it.

Comment: I did go back to letting Jetty handle this and ended up with the same issue for long playback, the video skips to the end if you play with seek feature and it happens after +-3/4 of playback. I will continue to investigate & propose only download option for large videos. Thanks